# multiple promises inside promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I wanted to make `then` chain but my promise was getting resolved before the inner promise execution. How can I fix this?

This code is working fine but I want to make it linear promises chain

```
functiontest(abc):Promise<any> {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     this.nativeStorage.getItem('test')
    .then(test => {
            if(test == 1) {
                this.function2(abc).then(tagId=>{
                    this.function3(tagId).then(data=>{
                        resolve(data)
                    });
                });
            }else {
                this.function3(abc).then(data=>{
                    resolve(data)
                });
            }         
        },
        error => {
            this.function2(abc).then(tagId=>{
                this.function3(tagId).then(data=>{
                    resolve(data)
                });
            });       
        }
    )      
});  }
```

`function3` uses the results of `function2` only if `function2` is called otherwise `function3` is called directly

Comment: It's a "callback hell" all over again.

Comment: @palaѕн right. That's what I am trying to avoid because that is the motive of promises

Comment: `function3` uses the results of `function2` only if `function2` is called otherwise `function3` is called directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is really too complicated for what it is actually doing. There is no need to use `new Promise` when you already get one from `getItem` and you should avoid the nesting of promise handlers like `.then(...then(....then()))`.

The following code should be functionally equivalent to yours:

```
function test(abc): Promise<any> {
  return this.nativeStorage.getItem('test')
    .then(test => {
      if (test == 1) {
        return this.function2(abc);
      }
      return abc;
    })
    .catch(() => this.function2(abc))
    .then(tagId => this.function3(tagId));
}
```

You might also want to look into `async`/`await` as a way to implement asynchronous functionality in an easier manner.

Comment: how to get the result of `function3` as resolved data?

Comment: `test(arg).then(theReturnValueFromFunction3 => { /* do something */ })`

Comment: thanks, @str. if I don't return anything, will the next `then` still be called. I am talking about the `else` condition in which only `function3` needs to be called

Comment: Yes. When you don't explicitly return anything, the function implicitly returns `undefined` which is equal to a resolved promise. The callback in `then` will be called with `undefined` as a argument, but you don't seem to be interested in them anyway.

Comment: I tried this approach but the same problem. Gets resolved earlier than it should.Actually, `function3` uses the result of `function2`

Comment: *"function3 uses the result of function2"*: that is not how it is in your question. Please edit it.

Comment: Please be more specific. *What* gets resolved too early (before *what*)? Please edit your question and add a complete example of your implementation and how you call it.

Comment: @GauravChaudhary I updated the answer to handle `tagId`.

Comment: using `throw` inside `if` instead of the `function` call worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using typescript the best way to make this code more readable is to use async/await:

```
class testclass {
    // Dummy declaration so the code compiles
    function2: (abc: any) => Promise<string>;
    function3: (abc: any) => Promise<string>;
    nativeStorage: {
        getItem: (p: string) => Promise<number>;
    }
    async test(abc): Promise<any> {
        try {
            let test = await this.nativeStorage.getItem('test')
            if (test == 1) {
                let tagId = this.function2(abc);
                return await this.function3(abc);
            } else {
                return await this.function3(abc)
            }
        }
        catch {
            let tagId = await this.function2(abc)
            return await this.function3(abc)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could declare `catch` without `error`: `catch { ... }`.

Comment: @Paleo You are right, as long as we are taking advantage of TS syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you seem to be stuck I think you may want to think about what the control flow of your application should be because it currently doesn't make much sense when looking at your code and then at your comments. Then test it with mocks and then test it with real functions.

Here is the simplified functionTest function that does what your code does (impossible to do what you want in the comments because that conflicts with what your code actually does). With mock thisObject (you could set thisObject with actual this when you got the control flow right).

```js
const later = value => 
  new Promise(
    (resolve,reject)=>
      setTimeout(
        _=>resolve(value),
        1000
      )
  )
const thisObject = {
  getItem : item => {
    if(item===-1){
      const p = Promise.reject("nope");
      p.catch(ignore=>ignore);//stops the console from shouting
      console.log("in getItem, rejecting with 'nope'");
      return later(p);//return rejected promise without rejection handled
    }
    console.log("in getItem resolving to:"+item);
    return later(item);
  },
  function2 : item => {
    console.log("in function2 with argument:",item);
    return later("function2")
  },
  function3 : item => {
    console.log("in function 3 with argument:",item);
    return later("function3-"+item)
  }
}
const functionTest = abc => {
  //thisObject=this
  return thisObject.getItem(abc)
  .then(//if getItem succeeds
    test =>
      //call fn2 or fn3 with abc (do not pass getitem result to the functions)
      //  depending on getItem result
      (test == 1)
        ? thisObject.function2(abc)//1: call function2 with abc
        : thisObject.function3(abc),//not 1: cll function3 with abc
    error =>//if getItem fails
      //call function2 with abc and function3 with result of function2
      thisObject.function2(abc)
      .then(
        tagId =>
          thisObject.function3(tagId)
      )
  );
}
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(
  (el,index)=>el.addEventListener(
    "click",
    e=>
      functionTest(index-1)
      .then(
        result=>console.log("finished, result is:",result)
      )
  )
);
```

```html
<input type="button" value="getItem that rejects">
<input type="button" value="getItem that resolves to 0">
<input type="button" value="getItem that resolves to 1">
```